# How to map Dataset and Typed Dataset using Automapper?

Tags: .net

I am trying to assign values from Dataset(Dataset.Table(0)) to a Typed Dataset(XSD) and vice verse. And my dataset.table(0) and typed dataset has same structure. I am trying to map between this two using Automapper but i am not getting how to do that one.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I have used DataSets but isn't this what Merge is for?

```
myds.Merge( ds );
```

I think there will be too many properties on the DataTable to have to ignore etc it will be a pain. You would do the mapping from the two datarows not the datasets.

It would be something like

```
.ForMember( trow => trow.MemberName, o => o.MapFrom( row => row["MemberName"] ) )
```

You would convert the List of DataRows.